# The certificate was not found. Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web

Tags: xdb, certificate

This is a follow up on this question [Experience Analytics fails on Sitecore 9.0.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11686/experience-analytics-fails-on-sitecore-9-0-1) that does not appear to have a solution.

The issue at hand is:

> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message: The certificate was not found.
>   Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web

I find several articles articles on troubleshooting that have not really assisted me. In the articles, it appears that other developers like myself are spending hours troubleshooting this and probably also like me are taking guesses as to why it fails.

Does anyone have a reliable set of troubleshooting steps for this issue? Or a reliable way of setting this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the following possible areas to figure this out

1. Validate that thumbprint from xconnect.collection.certificate is correct. Note that thumbprint value is case-sensitive. To get correct value you can open powershell and run command like: `Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -DnsName "your.client.cert.dns*"`. Use value from the output if it differs from value in xconnect.collection.certificate.
2. Make sure thumbprint on the key xconnect.collection.certificate in connection string config file matches with the  thumbprint found in corresponding xconnect site App config(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site.xconnect\App_Config).
3. Verify the thumbprint of xconnect client matches with the thumbprint provided in connection string of the site and app config(path provided in step 1) of xConnect site.
   [image]

4. Verfiy that the xConnect site works and navigating to xConnect site using https does not shw any error.(valid https certificate is shown?).
5. Verify if connection string(connectionstring.config) key xconnect.collection and all other xconnect related keys are pointed to correct xConnect site.

Comment: I had the same problem.  The thumbprint that was in the config file was incorrect.   I would also add that if the thumbprint is wrong in the appsettings for the xconnect website, that it might also be wrong in the config files for the services located under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site.xconnect\app_data\jobs.  The services will fail to start if the the specified certificate is invalid.

Comment: I ended up cleaning my machine and doing an install from scratch. This got me past the certificate not found, but I was stopped at step 3 in the answer. Turned out the certificate was not on site binding. I added that which got me further, but then I ran into Forbidden Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web. I used this article https://sitecorecorner.com/2017/10/25/sitecore-9-xconnect-ssl-and-that-403-forbidden/ to get through that.

Comment: Just a note here in case others are working with Sitecore in windows containers. We were seeing this error in our Sitecore CM container, it was appearing when hitting the content editor (ie `/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Editor.aspx`). I followed these steps and everything was correct (thumbprints matched up, certs in place). Simply stopping and starting the container fixed the problem. Unsure why this was happening, possibly networking with the container and docker was screwed up.

Comment: In my case, i have changed the currentuser to LocalMachine in config file and also verified the connection string.