# Unable to connect to site and see site content n Horizon 10.1

Tags: horizon

Whenever I launch "**Horizon**" it's showing a "**refused to connect**" message.

Why it doesn't connect to my site? Why I don't see any site content in Horizon?

I found the below error in the Sitecore log:

> ERROR Exception when executing agent
> aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent` error from the log suggests that you have an issue with Sitecore Analytics. If you go to the Experience Analytics app in the Sitecore Launchpad then you must see some errors highlighted in red at the top and in the browser console.

Very likely it is down to the certificates. Check for any certificate related errors in the log, the most common one is `The certificate was not found.`. If this is your case then the resolution has been already explained [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/the-certificate-was-not-found-source-sitecore-xdb-common-web).